# Problems with running 2 JavaScript "onload" functions

Tags: javascript, html

I have two JavaScript "onload" functions that I am trying to run on a webpage: a visual timer and a auto refresh function. I have implemented both in my webpage but although the timer runs, the Auto Refresh function will not run unless I remove the visual timer function from the script.

Here is the code for the webpage:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<script type="text/JavaScript">
<!--
function timedRefresh(timeoutPeriod) {
setTimeout("location.reload(true);",timeoutPeriod);
}
//   -->
</script>
<TITLE>test</TITLE>
</head>
<body onload="JavaScript:timedRefresh(15000); timedText();">

<script>
window.onload = timedText;
function timedText() {
var txt = document.getElementById('txt'),
 counter = 15;
var timer = setInterval(function () {
 if(counter === 0) return clearInterval(timer);
 txt.value = counter + " seconds";
 counter--;
}, 1000);
}
</script>
<input type="text" id="txt" />

</body></HTML>
```

Any help in solving this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with a small change:call `timedRefresh()` inside `window.onload's timetext()` function not in body onload.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<script type="text/JavaScript">
<!--
function timedRefresh(timeoutPeriod) {
setTimeout("location.reload(true);",timeoutPeriod);
}
//   -->
</script>
<TITLE>test</TITLE>
</head>
<body>

<script>
window.onload = timedText;
function timedText() {
var txt = document.getElementById('txt'),
 counter = 15;
timedRefresh(15000);
var timer = setInterval(function () {
 if(counter === 0) return clearInterval(timer);
 txt.value = counter + " seconds";
 counter--;
}, 1000);
}
</script>
<input type="text" id="txt" />

</body></HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the second one overrides the first. That is what you should be using [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) to add events.

```
window.addEventListener('load', timedText, false);
window.addEventListener('load', function(){timedRefresh(15000);}, false);
```

and if you need to support older IEs you need to look at [attachEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener#Legacy_Internet_Explorer_and_attachEvent)

BUT looking at the code why are you running two setTimeouts when all you need to do is when it hits zero call the redirect.

Comment: The 2nd overrides the first? `timedRefresh(15000)` comes before `timedText()` in the body "onload" and the timed text is the only one that works unless I delete it and then the timed refresh works.

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple onload events using the addEventListener method, like so:

```
window.addEventListener("load", timedText, false);
window.addEventListener("load", timedRefresh(15000), false);

function timedText() {
        var txt = document.getElementById('txt'),
            counter = 15;
        var timer = setInterval(function() {
            if (counter === 0) return clearInterval(timer);
            txt.value = counter + " seconds";
            counter--;
        }, 1000);
}

function timedRefresh(timeoutPeriod) {
    setTimeout("location.reload(true);",
    timeoutPeriod);
}
```

You can find out more information about addEventListener [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener).

Here's [a working codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NPNdYp).